# Getting best path between two points?

Tags: gps, maps, road, direction, driving

Last night we were moving from point 'A' to point 'B'. We are quite familiar with the road way and the directions, but not so sure. So just for the confirmation we tried to use the Google maps and the Nokia maps (provides a better directions here in India). And not so surprisingly both the services failed to provide even near matching directions. We were just a half KM away (roadway tww lanes each side) from the destination and Google maps was like a destination is 27Km away. Nokia maps was a little closer with 11 Km of travel.

On this problem a little idea stroked back in my mind, Following are the details

1. We all travel from some point 'A' to some point 'B' on a daily basis, and as we live in that region and/ or travel frequently on the same path we probably have found the shortest path for the destination.
2. Generally 60% of us do carry a location aware device with us daily. Be it a Cell phone tablet or any such device with GPS capabilities.
3. Here I am assuming that both point 'A' and point 'B' are well known points(on any map service google, apple microsoft any) and or we get some identification information about those points either from user or preinstalled devices or anything

---

1. Is it possible to record the path/directions we took and share same with rest of the world. Other people would search for directions between point 'A' and point 'B' and we could return a shortest path we have recorded or a list of all.
2. Is it doable?
3. What all problems we may face here?

Comment: If you're talking about a road or a location that's unknown to Google and Nokia, you should consider submitting it to OpenStreetMap.

Comment: I don't think the road(4 lanes probably 60ft road) is unknown to Google, It is displayed on maps. but somehow the service is not capable to return the best path.

Comment: This is a good question and an interesting idea - however, you might want to focus in on one of the aspects - I would say it's certainly doable from a technical perspective, probably the problems are what you want to focus on.

Comment: Hey sorry @Stev_k, but i didn't get you. What do you mean by "what you want to focus on". I am not an ideator, i am just a software engineer with no knowledge of GIS. Any guidance from your side is appreciated. Thanks man...

Comment: I think this is part of the premise of the Waze app. Also, you might consider posting about collecting user-suggested-route data on the OpenStreetMaps mailing list. They already collect GPS traces for creating map data, so some of the infrastructure is already there.

Comment: I mean focus on some of the problems rather than whether it's possible. You asked three separate questions when probably one would do, and the idea of stack exchange is to ask one discreet question in each post

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but it's not a very efficient way of routing. Very few people would want to use the exact starting & ending point as you. It is much more useful to know which are the roads, which are the directions, and the turns and crossroads.

The problem with services like Google maps in India, is that while traveling,  we use a variety of optimizations like the route with the least amount of traffic, the road with less number of portholes, and so on rather than just the shortest path. Google and other web services do not have input information for most of these parameters.They tend to just find the closest big road, and tend to route based on those. That is why the route a local takes, is more often than not, quicker and better than what these services suggest. If youtry to run

It would be more productive if we resolve the root cause of the problems, rather than suggesting inefficient solutions.